# How can I stop video recording if iphone's storage will soon be full?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetwriter

is there a way that I can be notified if device storage will is almost full while recording a video.

I found that you can set `maxRecordedFileSize`
  of a recording if I use `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` but unfortunately I cant use this, because I have to do some video manipulation before the video frames are stored in a video file.

Instead I have to use approach with `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVAssetWriter`.

Is it possible to observe for some kind of system notification that notify when storage is full?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get available free space in the disk

```
-(uint64_t)getFreeDiskspace{
    uint64_t totalSpace = 0.0f;
    uint64_t totalFreeSpace = 0.0f;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[paths lastObject] error: &error];

    if (dictionary) {
        NSNumber *fileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemSize];
        NSNumber *freeFileSystemSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
        totalSpace = [fileSystemSizeInBytes floatValue];
        totalFreeSpace = [freeFileSystemSizeInBytes floatValue];
        NSLog(@"Memory Capacity of %llu MiB with %llu MiB Free memory available.", ((totalSpace/1024ll)/1024ll), ((totalFreeSpace/1024ll)/1024ll));
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error Obtaining System Memory Info: Domain = %@, Code = %@", [error domain], [error description]);
    }

    return totalFreeSpace;
}
```

and you can check like

```
if([self getFreeDiskspace]>100.0){
  //The store 
}else{
  //Alert user
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try and report when finished with testing. Thanks